# why spinner disappear sometimes and reappear again after Minimizing the app?

Tags: java, android, view, spinner, adapter

i am trying to make web devoloping app but i am facing problem in the spinner,
its disappear some times and i dont know the reason..
this when i set the adapter to the spinner:-

[image: image1]

[image: image3]

and this when i minimize the app and open it again:-
[image: image1]
i can click the spinner and the drop down menu appear,but i cant select item:-
[image]
xml:-
https://anotepad.com/notes/kxcp7n2h

Comment: It may be necessary to add the relative layout/code files to your question to help answerers.

Comment: i added it now.